# How to remove non alphanumeric characters and write to a file without using any built in libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My question is that the python takes the characters from an input file and it converts all the non alphabetic characters to a space " " and makes all the characters uppercase and writes it to another file. We are not allowed to use built in libraries such as regular expression. 
Following is my code

```
    #Reading the file
ifile = open('test.txt','r')

#Reading the characters of the file and stripping it by words
data = ifile.read().split()

x = str(data).upper()

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                  'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
file = open("split.txt",'w')

for char in data:
        if char.isalpha():
            file.write(char)
        else:
                char.replace(char,' ')
```

This code executes but it does not write anything to split.txt file where as in the requirements it should remove the non alphabets and write all the characters in upper case
Eg:- If input from test.txt file is "Hello_Wo!rld" then the output from the split.txt file should be "HELLO WO RLD"

Comment: The last line merely replaces the `char` without actually writing it to the file.

Comment: You also don't use the `letters` array

Answer (score 1):

Add ifile.close() at the end and see if it works.

Also `char.replace(char,' ')` should be `file.write(' ')` because right now this doesn't write anything.

As egur pointed out, you are not using the letters array, same for the x variable.

Comment: letters array and x variable would be used after the replacing part works fine i have removed that for now

Comment: Ah that makes sense, so does it work with the close() ?

Comment: Simply after adding the file.close and changing char.replace to file.write the output removes all the spaces and the whole word that contains non aplhabetic characters

input was Helloworld helloworld hello_world
output was Helloworldhelloworld

Comment: Ok so I think that `ifile.read().split()` is using whitespaces as separator so this returns the list `["Helloworld", "helloworld", "hello_world"]`. So in your for you actually iterate over each whole word. Therefore `char.isalpha()` means "Is there only letters in this word?".

Maybe try to remove the split().

Comment: Solved it by the help of valentinRssl I appreciate it :)